# What is the result of replacing potential function in time independent Schrodinger's wave equation by the potential function in Poisson's equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, schroedinger-equation, semiconductor-physics, nanoscience

[image][image]

[image]

I have to couple above two equations
and put the value of V from Poisson's to Schrodinger's equation and I am doing so to understand the mechanics of MOSFETs.
I have studied most topics in quantum mechanics and would really appreciate some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The charge density is given by
$$
\rho(x,y,z) = |\psi(x,y,z)|^2,
$$
so you have a closed system of (nonlinear) equations for the wave function and the potential.

You can now use the [general solution of Poisson equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation#Statement_of_the_equation)
$$
V(x,y,z)=-\iiint dx' dy' dz' \frac{|\psi(x,y,z)|^2}{4\pi\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+z-z')^2}}
$$
(needs to be adjusted for the system of units that you use - I leave it for you, since this is really a homework problem.)